# Change Printer preferences / Driver Settings in C#

Tags: c#, printing, driver, xps, inf

I am trying to print an existing XPS file in GrayScale . 
I tried to add a PrintTicket inside the XPS file, and also tried to change the PrintQueue property of the printer , like :

```
     LocalPrintServer server = new   LocalPrintServer(PrintSystemDesiredAccess.AdministrateServer);
      PrintQueue pq = server.GetPrintQueue("MyPrinterName");
      pq.DefaultPrintTicket.OutputColor = OutputColor.Grayscale;
      PrintSystemJobInfo print = pq.AddJob("myPrintJob", "MyFileToPrint.xps",false);
```

But still printing the file in colors ...

So , I thinking about changing the print setting in the driver settings itself , like :

[image]

[image]

So , Is it possible to change this option programmatically ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing global state to solve a local problem is usually a bad idea. Submitting a print ticket with the job should allow the sort of control you are looking for. Have you tried something like this?

```
LocalPrintServer server = new LocalPrintServer(PrintSystemDesiredAccess.AdministrateServer);
PrintQueue pq = server.GetPrintQueue("MyPrinterName");
var jobTicket = pq.DefaultPrintTicket;
jobTicket.OutputColor = OutputColor.Grayscale;
PrintSystemJobInfo print = pq.AddJob("myPrintJob", "MyFileToPrint.xps", false, jobTicket);
```

Comment: thanks for the proposal , but unfortunately still printing in color .
the target printer is xps based (  brother generic jpeg type1 class driver )

Comment: If that is the case, then altering the print preferences is unlikely to help - neither the print driver nor the printer are honoring the outputcolor field. This would indicate that the driver expects the conversion to grayscale to occur during the creation of the xps document, rather than during printing.

Comment: I tried to print Gray-Scaled xps file , butt still prints in color .
Its clear that the PrintTicket inside the xps will be completely neglected .
Thanks anyway for your answer ...